# How to disable TLS Secure Renegotiation on apache httpd 2?

Tags: apache, openssl

I'm trying to disable TLS Renegotiation on apache httpd 2 but without success.
I've tried adding the following on my /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

```
[system_default_sect]
Options = SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION
```

No success.

Then added the following on my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire +StdEnvVars -OptRenegotiate
```

Even after these changes, when I try the command below I still receive the message "Secure Renegotiation IS supported":

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

I'm using the apache on a WSL with Ubuntu 22.

I really appreciate any help.